# Problema para mostrar datos con Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

estoy empezando a aprender Vue.js, en el ejemplo que estoy siguiendo, debo construir una lista de la siguiente manera

```
<div id="app">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Agregar una tarea</h1>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Lista de tareas</h1>
            <div class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item"
                v-for="item in lists">
                  @{{ item.keep }}
              </li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h2>Consulta</h2>
            <pre>
               @{{ $data | json }}
            </pre>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
```

**Script.js**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',  
  data: {
    lists: [
      { keep: 'uno', completed: false },
      { keep: 'dos', completed: false },
    ],
  }
});
```

El tema es que en el navegador @ {{ item.keep }} se imprime de forma literal y sin @ es lo mismo.

Gracias desde ya.

Comment: cambia el orden: primero `vue.js` y después `script.js`... tienes que abrir tu consola y verás los fallos probablemente

Comment: @BlackSheep Gracias! Ese era el problema.